# Facebook php sdk stopped returning api values

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have been using the Facebook php sdk since August 2011 to do our oauth registration and validation. Sometime last month it broke. By broke i mean the $me = $facebook->api('/me'); 
call suddenly started returning a blank array - no errors thrown nothing. 
No changes have been made to this part of the system for several months.

I took this as an opportunity to migrate to v3.1.1 but that had no effect.

We are running a php page inside a jsp/Tomcat installation so we are using quercus. Ive run this as plain php and get the same results.

Since I have not seen a general alarm raised I assume it must be something in our site but I cannot isolate anything. Any idea? Here is the php code ( we have a user so we are in the AUTHENTICATED block of code - the $me array contains nothing)

```
<?php
$request = quercus_servlet_request();
$page = $request->getAttribute("page");

include_once 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $request->getAttribute("appId"),
'secret' => $request->getAttribute("secretKey"),
'cookie' => true
));


if(is_null($facebook->getUser())) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => $request-  >getAttribute("canvasUrl"),'req_perms' => 'publish_stream'));
    $page->Log("LOGIN URL",$url);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location.href = '$url';</script>";
    exit;
} else {
    try {
        $page->Log("AUTH","AUTHENTICATED");
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        $page->Log("UID",$uid);
        $page->Log("ME array",print_r($me, true));

        $request->getSession()->setAttribute("authenticated","T");
        $request->getSession()->setAttribute("fbuid",strval($uid) );
        $request->getSession()->setAttribute("fname",$me['first_name']);
        $request->getSession()->setAttribute("lname",$me['last_name']);
        $request->getSession()->setAttribute("accesstoken",$facebook- >getAccessToken());
    //$page->Log("fbuid",$request->getSession()->getAttribute("fbuid"));
```

.......

Answer (score 1):

Right now facebook is having some down time all over the world. You might see some strange issues.

But you should consider testing you app using graph API explorer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=1274834235) and confirm issue is on your side or facebook
[image]

Select your app on right top and query the API.

For me its working fine(India).